# ¿Como puedo realizar esta estructura en Json desde SQL 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo convertir esta estructura seleccionando dato desde tabla al seleccioanrlo lo voy a convertir en JSON desde base de datos Sql 2017. ADJUNTO MI QUERY

```
Select Medio_Pago AS [medio_pago] from Table_FacturacionElect 
where Comprobante = '22'  FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Deseo tener este resultado excato

```
 "medio_pago": [
        "sample string 1"
      ],
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. El resultado que quieres no es un JSON válido. Intenta: **`Select Medio_Pago AS [medio_pago] from Table_FacturacionElect 
where Comprobante = '22'  FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('medio_pago')`**  o bien así: **`Select Medio_Pago AS [medio_pago] from Table_FacturacionElect 
where Comprobante = '22'  FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('medio_pago'), WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`**. [Ver la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) para más detalles. Si no funciona di el error.

Comment: En la primera Opcion que me comentas **Select Medio_Pago AS [medio_pago] from Table_FacturacionElect where Comprobante = '22' FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('medio_pago')**  Me genera este Json **{"medio_pago":[{"medio_pago":"04"}]}** lo que quiero es quitarle las llaves dentro el noto y solo dejar [ ]

Comment: Pero ¿por qué quieres hacer eso? No sería un JSON válido. Si no quieres un JSON entonces haz lo que quieras hacer manualmente. Ahora bien, no te lo recomiendo si esos datos tienen que ser consumidos o devueltos como JSON.

Comment: Me genera este Json **{"medio_pago":[{"medio_pago":"04"}]}** pero gustaria tener este resultado  **{  "medio_pago":"medio_pago":["04"]  }**

Comment: Si quieres algo así tienes que hacerlo manual, porque eso no es un JSON válido y no podrás leerlo como JSON, mientras que el primero sí lo es y lo podrás leer fácilmente. [Puedes verificarlo aquí](https://jsonlint.com) pegando cada uno y dando al botón  **`Validate JSON`**

Comment: **  "medio_pago": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ]**  Entonces realizar esta estructura no es valida para generarlo desde sql

Comment: No, esa estructura no es válida. Esta es lo más parecido a lo que quieres: **`{
  "medio_pago": ["str1", "str2"]
 }`**, esa sí es válida, lo puedes verificar en `jsonlint`

Comment: exacto es lo que ocupo amigo, pero generarlo desde sql

Comment: ¿Tú quieres todos los resultados sin importar nada más dentro de un array o son resultados agrupados por algún campo?

Comment: Son todos los resultados que tenga de mi busquedad generando dicho json

Comment: A.Cedano ya pude realizar esta estructura que queria, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('["',Medio_Pago,'"]')) ValidityPeriod 
from Table_FacturacionElect 
where Comprobante = '22' 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Utilice este query para poder tener este resultado.

Comment: esto responde a tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿Qué resultado arroja esa consulta exactamente? Yo no la puedo probar con éxito, me da error.

Comment: {"medio_pago":["04","04"]}   SQL para Json esta disponible del 2016 para adelante